# Tomcat 9 rewrite url problem Only First Rule Works, Others Are Not Applied

Tags: apache, url, tomcat, url-rewriting, rules

Description:
I'm facing an issue with my Apache Rewrite Rules configuration where only the first rule is working, and the subsequent rules are not being applied as expected. I need help troubleshooting and fixing this problem.

Problem Details:
I have defined multiple RewriteCond and RewriteRule directives in my configuration file to rewrite URLs based on certain conditions. However, it seems that only the first rule is functioning correctly, and the rest of the rules are not being considered.

Example Configuration:
Here's a simplified version of my configuration:

apache
Copy code
RewriteEngine On

## First Rule (Working)

RewriteRule ^/app1 /app1/index.html [L]

## Second Rule (Not Working)

RewriteRule ^/app2 /app2/index.html [L]

## Third Rule (Not Working)

RewriteRule ^/app3 /app3/index.html [L]

In this example, only the first rule works as expected. The second and third rules are not being applied, resulting in unexpected behavior.

What I've Tried:

I've checked the order of the rules to ensure that the first rule isn't unintentionally overriding the others.
I've verified that the conditions specified in the second and third rules are being met for the test cases I'm using.
I've enabled RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to troubleshoot, but I don't see any errors or indications of why the second and third rules are failing.
Question:
Can someone help me identify why the second and third RewriteRules are not working as expected? Is there a potential conflict or issue with my configuration that I'm overlooking?

I'm facing an issue with my Apache Rewrite Rules configuration where only the first rule is working, and the subsequent rules are not being applied as expected. I need help troubleshooting and fixing this problem.

Comment: This seems to be a configuration question, not about a programming problem - see the [tag:apache] tag's description and [help/on-topic]. You might also want to take the [tour]. Also, your question title and tags mention Tomcat, but your question has no indication of Tomcat whatsoever. Also: "not working" and "resulting in unexpected behavior" could be anything. [ask] has some description - please be more descriptive about what you observe and expect.

Comment: I use Tomcat with the rewrite vavle, and in my /webapps/blog/WEB-INF/rewrite.config I have two rules but the first one works, if I comment out the first the second one will work : message The requested resource [/blog/app2] is not available (404)